# Sharepoint 2016 Sandbox Solution with Site Template disappearing

Tags: sharepoint-server

when we create a site template via "Save site as template" after a short while (less than 1hour i think) the solution for this template in the solution gallery of the site collection is disappearing (also in the Windows Explorer view of the solution gallery).

The Feature "Web Template feature of exported web template" is still there and activated, the template can still be selected when creating a new subsite.

The site can be saved as a template with the same name with no error, but then there are two custom site templates with the same name when we create a new subsite.

Does anyone know this problem?

The content database of this site has been migrated from a Sharepoint 2013 environment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the site without migrating has this issue? Maybe you can create a new site collection and test again. Also go to Recycle Bin, check if the solution is here.

Comment: No the issue only occurs on this migrated site

Comment: Did you run Test-SPContentDatabase before you mount content database? Are there any errors when running it? Check if this missing solution is in Recycle Bin.  As the new site could work well, please try to export the problematic site and import it to the new site, check if it could work after importing on the new site.

Comment: Test-SPContentDatabase doesn't show any errors, the solutions are not in the recycle bin